# Entity Framework 4.1 Performance issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am currently using Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project.
And I am getting severe performance issues while looping through the records in the view to display them.

The data is being recieved quickly, so I know it's not the connection to our remote oracle server and there are no lazy loaded relationships in the model I'm using, yet each record is taking 120-300ms to process a simple 3 field output with an action link.

Currently it takes over 3 minutes to load the page with 800ish records.

I've tried tweaking with configuration options but none seem to help.

Anyone has any ideas?

edit: controller code

```
readonly OracleSampleManagerContext db = new OracleSampleManagerContext();

public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
        var spList = db.SamplePoints.OrderBy(e=>e.Id).ToList(); 
        return View(MVC.Reports.Views.SamplePointList, spList);
}

    <h2>
    Selection By Sample Point
</h2>

<table>
@foreach (var sp in Model)
{
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new  System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

    <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(sp.Id, MVC.Reports.Results(sp.Id))</td>
        <td>@sp.Description</td>
        <td>@sp.PointLocation</td>
        <td>@sw.ElapsedMilliseconds</td>
    </tr>

    sw.Stop();
    sw.Reset();
}

</table>
```

Example:

```
0200    72" Sewer to river - Once through cooling water     OUTFALLS    346ms
0400    66" Sewer to river - Combined effluent  OUTFALLS    347ms
0500    54" Sewer to river - Once through cooling water     OUTFALLS    388ms
06-AI-18    TBA in Water    IB2     228ms
06-AI-31    TBA in Water    IB2     172ms
```

Comment: Your're going to have to show us more. How ae you populating the model?  What is MVC.Reports.Results() doing?

Comment: Is the query actually being executed when `Model` is created? For example, are you doing a `ToList()` at that time?

Comment: and this is a tiny nitpick, but you should move the declaration line of the stop watch to outside of the loop

Comment: you should anyway enable paging if disabled or decrease the page size, 800 records per page are too many. This not to say your optimization is not good but after you optimized what is slow, also show less records per page ;-)

Comment: the stop watch i just added to time the record processing because it was slow  it ss being converted to a list before sending to the view and i may add paging if necessary but my boss want as few pages as possible so im trying to cut down paging as much as possible ill up date teh original post with the code im uing to populate the list as well

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink(sp.Id, MVC.Reports.Results(sp.Id))`? Fetching data inside a view? Performance problems are the least problem with this code. Views are for displaying data, not for fetching. Or maybe I am mistaken and that's a T4 template?

Comment: What does `MVC.Reports.Reults` do?

Comment: MVC. is the prefix used by the T4MVC T4 template code generator. It generatres a very simple class hierarchy to return URLs and contains no logic, let alone db queries. My guess is that he is lazy loading something, or that the properties accessed use something that is lazy loading something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `MVC.Reports.Results(sp.Id)` does some sort of db lookup, and since you converted your model to a list before sending it to the view, you now have to hit the database again for each record  Making a page of 800 records require 801 seperate trips to the database instead of one.

1. Remove the ToList() from your first query.
2. Refactor MVC.Reports.Results(sp.Id) to take an object instead of an int, and within that method work on the object directly.

Both of the above may require you to move the scope of your entities context from within the action out to the Controller.

Comment: before you do all of that you could move the timer output to before you call actionlink

Comment: the timer is being removed it was only put there temporarily to find the root cause of the performance issue

Comment: the context is currently global to the controller already but ill try your other suggestions and get back to you

Comment: turns out 2/3s of the problem was due to network issues on our vpn server as i was testing from home but the post did partially help so im giving you the rep for the answer =)